# This code is generating a segment core dump

Tags: c, linked-list

This code is generating a
segment core dump.

```
typedef struct linked{
        int val;
        struct linked *index;
}linked;


    struct linked *temp1;

     int count=1;
     while(count<10){

           temp1->val=count;
           temp1=temp1->index;

           count++;

     } //end of while

     while(temp1!=NULL){
           printf(" %d\n",temp1->val);
           temp1=temp1->index;
     }
```

Comment: 1) allocate for `temp1`. 2) `while(temp1!=NULL){` : `temp1` not top of list now.

Comment: I think you're not ready for linked lists. You need to consider much simpler experiments with `malloc` and `free`. Do you know how to allocate memory? Do you know what a pointer is?

Comment: You need to keep allocating memory for new nodes. It may be a good idea to follow Aaron McDaid advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
struct linked *temp1, *top;
int count;

temp1 = top = calloc(1, sizeof(*top));
for(count=1;count<10;count++){
    temp1->val = count;
    if(count < 10 -1)//not last
        temp1 = temp1->index = calloc(1, sizeof(*temp1));
}
temp1 = top;
 while(temp1!=NULL){
    printf(" %d\n",temp1->val);
    temp1=temp1->index;
}
```

Comment: Technically speaking this answer is correct, but I will exercise my right to downvote an answer that I consider unhelpful.

Comment: I do not care even if you do not like. I pointed out point should be already improved. Code shows a specific correction method.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct linked *temp1 = malloc(sizeof(struct linked));
```

Allocate memory to your pointer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still segmentation core dump.

Comment: Allocating temp1 with malloc doesn't initialize temp1->index.  The second time through the loop, you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @Annie Please understand using pointers. `temp1->index` is not initialzied and you are using it which causes seg fault

Answer (score 1):

In

```
struct linked *temp1;

int count=1;
while(count<10){

      temp1->val=count;
```

`temp1` is never made to point to anything.